# cryptoPP AES, weird encryption output

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++

I am new and testing out cryptoPP, I am trying out to encrypt a single character at a time using cryptoPP, I notice some characters do not encrypt properly and exhibit weird behaviour like more or less than 16 characters, or weird arrangements.

The code I am using is:

```
std::string data;
std::cin >> data;

std::string plaintext = data;

std::string ciphertext;
byte key[16 ] = {1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6} ; 
byte iv[ 16 ]={1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6};

memset( key, 0, sizeof(key));
memset( iv, 0, sizeof(iv) );

CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, 16);
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, iv );

CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) );
stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( plaintext.c_str() ), plaintext.length());
stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

std::cout << ciphertext << std::endl;

std::ofstream file("d:\\log.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
file.write(ciphertext.c_str(), ciphertext.size());
file.close();

system("PAUSE");
```

The decrypt code is as below:

```
byte key[16 ] = {1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6} ; 
byte iv[ 16 ]={1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6};

memset( key, 0, 16  );
memset( iv, 0, 16 );

std::string decryptedtext;
std::string test = get_file_contents("d:\\log.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < test.length() ; i += 16)  {

    std::string block = test.substr(i, i + 16);
    test.replace(i, i + 16, block);

    CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, 16);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption( aesDecryption, iv );

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ) );
    stfDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( block.c_str() ), 16 );
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
}

std::cout << decryptedtext << std::endl;

std::ofstream fout("d:\\aesencrypt.txt");
fout << decryptedtext;
```

It works if I do not type certain characters. Issues happen when I typed in the character "c" or "r", it becomes weird and I am unable to parse 16 characters when I decrypt. 
The decrypt will fail because the encrypted text are not in alignment or more or less than 16 characters.

Comment: AES does operations a block, not a character, at a time. CBC mode is also a block thing.  Something like counter (CTR) mode can do character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I run exactly your code without write/read to/from files and it works. (It works with 'c' and 'r' as well). I combined those two fragments into one, eliminated files and assigned `test = ciphertext;`. Perhaps the problem is with reading/writing into files...

It does not matter that you encrypt one character or more: CBC mode adds padding if the input is not a multiple of the block size.